# Can't Figure Out Article Review Schema Embed Code?

Tags: seo, schema.org

I'm trying to embed some schema in an article I've written which reviews a certain product. I'm using a Custom HTML block on WordPress to do this.

I basically just want the 4.8/5 stars to show on Google search results page... what do I need to fix as they're not showing currently?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/", 
  "@type": "Review", 
  "name": "Cool Cheese Grater",
  "image": "example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/coolcheese.jpg",
  "reviewRating": {
    "@type": "Rating",
    "ratingValue": "4.8",
    "author": "Harvey Meale",
    "itemReviewed": "Cool Cheese Grater"
        }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement review schema you should consider two things.
1-The script you wrote above should be inserted in the head of the page you created (In  tag)

2-For some snippets such as review or FAQ in addition to the code you insert in the , you should have the actual presence of that snippet too (e.g. for REVIEW snippets you need star rating html code implementation or for FAQ you need the actual question and answer content in the bottom of the main content.)

*You have an easier way to do this: You can install plugins like [KKSTAR Ratings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kk-star-ratings/)

**For inserting your desired code in head or footer you can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying.

Comment: I don't want any way for the reader to do the star rating, it's just a review of the product that I'm doing - the rating is mine and not an aggregation.

Comment: As I said if the physical implementation is done, the chance for the review snippet to be indexed increases a lot more, but there still exist a chance to be indexed there.